# Replace only the corners of a rotated image with a different color

Tags: java, image-rotation

I am currently making a game that requires the rotating of an image. In order to rotate it, I am using the following code.

```
public ManipulableImage rotate(double degrees){
    BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = rotatedImage.createGraphics();
    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2);
    /*
    ManipulableImage is a custom class that makes it easier to manipulate
    an image code wise.
    */
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    return new ManipulableImage(rotatedImage, true).replace(0, -1);
}
```

The code does rotate the image, but it leaves the corners black which should be transparent. My renderer recognizes the rgb value -1 as the transparent value, and doesn't change a pixel when that value is present. So, I would like to change the rgb values of the corners from 0 (black) to -1 (transparent).

The only problem is, I can't simply iterate through the image and replace the 
black pixels because there are other pixels in the original image that are black. So my question is, how do I replace only the black pixels created by the rotation.

(Sorry I couldn't provide examples of the image, I'm not sure how to screenshot with this computer.)

Comment: You can try making an algorithm that searches, given a point, all the neighbours with the same colour, and then iterate this neighbours. As the corners are black, if you start the iteration in the four corners, it should get all the 4 black areas.

Comment: That's not perfect either, given that there could be black pixels on the edges of the image.

Comment: Right, are the corners of the rotated original image on the edges of the new image?

Comment: Yes, and one thing I forgot to mention, the scale of the image is quite small (about 16 by 16), so chances are that there will be many instances of a black pixel on the corner or an edge touching one of the black corners created by rotating.

Comment: With the rotation, you can know the coordinates of the corners of the original image and, thus, find the triangles of the void areas.

Comment: `but it leaves the corners black which should be transparent.` - Not sure I understand? If the image is transparent it should not be an issue. If the background of the panel is black, then change the background of the panel. You can make the panel non-opaque.

Comment: Due to the fact that the hypotenuse of a rectangle is greater than either of the legs, when a rectangle is rotated, it's highest and lowest points change, as well does its left-most and right-most. When these points change, the edges that connect them rotate. In an un-rotated image, these edges are horizontal and vertical, but when the image is rotated, these edges also move and rotate. Since the image itself must stay within the confines of its pixel grid, the image either shrinks upon rotation, or the confines grow to preserve scale. The new area created are the black corners.

Comment: The graphics object has no context to color these new pixels, so it simply colors them black. I would like for it to color them to my transparent rgb value (-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The graphics object has no context to color these new pixels, so it simply colors them black.

```
BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

You should be using the following so the `BufferedImage` supports transparency:

```
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
```

Then in the painting code you can use:

```
g.setColor( new Color(0, 0, 0, 0) );
g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
g.rotate(...);
g.drawImage(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have the following rotation:

[image]

The green cells are the original image rotated, while the white ones the area you want to delete. From the rotation and the degrees given, you can know the coordinates of the red cells and thus, delete cells that meet the conditions:

```
(x_coord <= x1 and y_coord > x_coord * y1 / x1) /* Top Left */ or
(x_coord >= x2 and y_coord > x_coord * y2 / x2) /* Top Right */ or
(x_coord >= x3 and y_coord < x_coord * y3 / x3) /* Bottom Right */ or 
(x_coord <= x4 and y_coord < x_coord * y4 / x4) /* Bottom Left */
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yeah, and i'm guessing these conditions would be slightly altered for the other corners. Thanks. This should work great!